# Powers on R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot in R and one of my axes is labeled as `z^2`

```
plot(log(b)~a, data=dat, pch=15, xlab="time", ylab="log(z^2)")
```

Is it possible to write power in R without symbol "^" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see `?plotmath`.

```
plot(log(b)~a, data=dat, pch=15, xlab="time", ylab=expression(log(z^2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ylab=expression(log(z^2))`